# Associate multiple values with the single key and also maintain the order of values

Tags: java

I have a class which contain the following members

```
private String patientName;
private String patientPhoneNumber;
```

now I have multiple names attached with the phone No. for example

```
1234567, AAA
1234567, BBB
8765432, CCC
8765432, GGG
```

Now I want to store them in a Map but the phone No. should be the key having multiple values, for 1234567 i should have value AAA and BBB, please advise how can I store the multiple values with the single key in map here my key is Phone No. and then please let me know if I want to print in console then ow would I iterate over the Map

Also please not that I want to maintain the order also let say first I get the value AAA and then BBB so i should maintain these order also, since I get this is just a example but in my scenario I will be getting this value from backend so to maintain the order is also necessary please advise.

Comment: You can have a map return other collections not just "basic" types have your map return a **List** or a **Set** depending on what you need, that will allow you to associate multiple values with a key.

Comment: @BevynQ I request you to post a snap of code that will make understanding more clear

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
HashMap<String,LinkedList<String>> map
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Map<String, TreeSet<String>>()
```

Will allow you to store the values in a `TreeSet` (sorted...).

To print them:

```
for(Map.Entry entry : phoneBook.entries()){
    System.out.println(entry.key() + ":");
    TreeSet names = entry.value();
    for(String name : names){
        System.out.println("\t" + name);
    }
}
```

You can add, like this, if you want case insensitive ordering:

```
TreeSet<String> nameSet = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
phoneBook.add(number, nameSet);
```

Comment: it maintains a natural ordering, or given a comparator, but not the order of insertion.

Comment: @MouseEvent  I want to achieve that..!!preserve the order of values in each key

Comment: @YanickRochon assuming it's a phone book, insertion ordering, won't play a big role.

Comment: @MouseEvent, perhaps, but then you'd have to specify a custom `Comparator` nevertheless as the values won't necessarily be `String`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
private Map<String,List<String>> patients;

public void setPatientNumber(String number, String patient){
    List<String> list = patients.get(number);
    if(list == null){
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        patients.put(number,list);
    }
    list.add(patient);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for each values :

```
LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> phoneNumbers = new LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

// register new phone number
phoneNumbers.put("1234567", new ArrayList<String>());

// add names to the phone number
phoneNumbers.get("1234567").add("AAA");
phoneNumbers.get("1234567").add("BBB");
```

Both collections preserve the insertion ordering.

** **Edit** **

Here, this is roughly what you'd need (this was done on the spot without much testing, but you should get the idea). Since your ordering may vary, I thought limiting duplicates and providing a comparator for ordering should be preferable (as suggested by other answers) :

```
public class LinkedMultiMap<K,V> {

    private Comparator<V> comparator;
    private LinkedHashMap<K,Set<V>> entries;

    public LinkedMultiMap() {
        this(null);
    }

    public LinkedMultiMap(Comparator<V> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.entries = new LinkedHashMap<K, Set<V>>();
    }

    public boolean add(K key, V value) {
        if (!entries.containsKey(key)) {
            entries.put(key, new TreeSet<V>(comparator));
        }

        return entries.get(key).add(value);
    }

    public Collection<V> get(K key) {
        return entries.get(key);
    }

    public boolean remove(K key, V value) {
        boolean removed = false;
        if (entries.containsKey(key)) {
            removed = entries.get(key).remove(value);

            if (entries.get(key).isEmpty()) {
                entries.remove(key);
            }
        }
        return removed;
    }

    public Collection<V> removeAll(K key) {
        return entries.remove(key);
    }

    public Iterator<K> keyIterator() {
        return entries.keySet().iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to preserve the order of values in each key, not the order of keys themselves.

Comment: @YanickRochon  Thanks a lot do we have linkedHashMap multiValueMap sort of thing also in java or not let say i have use for another scenario where values were integer Map<String, Collection<Integer>> multiValueMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>>();

Comment: @user1924563, yes, you can use any type like that.

Comment: @MiserableVariable, perhaps, but it's *almost* as fast as a regular `HashMap`, so it's a value plus without much cost.

Comment: @YanickRochon but the only thing that I am worries is that I want to maintain the order of values also.

Comment: @MiserableVariable yeah I want to achieve that..!!preserve the order of values in each key

Comment: The arraylist will help you maintain order, but also see my reply below for a more convenient solution

Comment: @user1924563, the class suggested by MiserableVariable is somewhat a wrapper of what I'm proposing here. If you don't mind managing the implementation yourself, then my solution is exactly what you need. All you need to do is replace the `ArrayList<String>` with `ArrayList<YourType>` and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

> Associate multiple values with the single key

That is a [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html):

> A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values with a single key.

[LinkedHashMultimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html) from Google Collections seems to fit the bill:

> Implementation of Multimap that does not allow duplicate key-value
>   entries and that returns collections whose iterators follow the
>   ordering in which the data was added to the multimap.

If you don't want to add the dependency, you can use a collection as value type:

```
Map<String /*number*/, List<String> /*names*/> numbers;
```

Note that the former only allows retrieval in order of insertion, if you want to be able to change it you will have to use the latter hand-rolled solution

Comment: Google Collections has been unmaintained for several years now.  Did you mean Guava?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map` to store your data.  The keys should be `String` objects and the values should be `List` objects.  Using a `List` as the map entry value allows to associate multiple values with a single key.  A `List` will also maintain the order of adding elements.

Comment: Thanks, also please advise as I also want to preserve the order of values in each key so this approach will work there also

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Map<Integer,List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();

        //insert values into list one
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.add("AAA");
        list1.add("BBB");

        //insert values into list one
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2.add("CCC");
        list2.add("GGG");

        //insert values to keys
        //single key multiple values
        map.put(1234567, list1);
        map.put(8765432, list2);

        //iterating and displaying the values
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,List<String>> entry: map.entrySet() ) {

            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> values = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Value of " +key+ " is " +values);
            //System.out.println("Value of " +key+ " is " +values.get(0));
            //System.out.println("Value of " +key+ " is " +values.get(1));

        }
}
```